# Debugging issue in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I have written my code on my desktop machine in VB.net
I then transferred this code on to a local server in my university, and then tried debugging it.
It gave me the output web application
But then, when I changed my code  and then debugged it again, it  is not taking the changes I have made.
For ex:
I have removed the code completely from a form and then executed it, it did not give me any errors and the old code was executed.

Please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're working with a web application?

Here's the process I usually go through when I come across (what seems like) a caching issue:

1. Clean solution/project
2. Rebuild solution/project
3. Redeploy
4. Recycle application pool in IIS
5. Run `iisreset` from command prompt
6. Clear out browser cache
7. Restart browser

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem or not...

If you have errors in your code and it does not compile, it'll run the previous compiled code.

Check your build and run options:
Tools/Options.../Projects and Solutions/Build and Run.

Check the that the setting **On Run, when build or deployment errors occur:**
Change it to **Prompt to launch**.  If this setting is already set to this, then this is probably not the problem.